# System wide text select event

Tags: c#, events, select, text

Whenever any text is selected in any window, i want to capture the event in my application and generate a pop up. What event should i capture in C# to accomplish this?

Comment: This done via the windows API.  Simliar question is found here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251578/how-do-i-get-the-selected-text-from-the-focused-window-using-native-win32-api