# Read word from external application from the cursor position

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I have window application of Hotkey and pressing hotkey (e.g. Ctrl + 1) I want a text from the cursor position from the external application like notepad, notepad++, Microsoft Word, Browsers etc.

This functionality is already implemented in "WordWeb" Application Hotkey. The same functionality I expect.

Please help me with sample code if any one have idea.

Comment: in previous your question you should already have seen this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2698146/1997232).

Comment: None of the linked answered offer the possibility of the UIAutomation framework (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is no a simple way to do this. The possible ways are OCR, using of Accessibility API and winapi hooking. Probably you should narrow your problem statement before taking any further steps.

Comment: No ideas why that answer is downvoted... +1